# how to set authentication credentials for JMX in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jmx

I have enabled `JMX` in my `spring boot` application. I am able to set/get properties on using `Jconsole`. 
I want to add `authentication` (username/password) for connecting to the `MBeanServer`. I prefer annotation based if possible.

Here is my `JMXBean`.

```
@ManagedResource(objectName = "Examples:type=JMX,name=Resource")
public class Resource {
    List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManagedAttribute
    public String getLastItem() {
        return items.get(getSize()-1);
    }

    @ManagedAttribute
    public int getSize() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @ManagedOperation
    public void addItem(String item) {
        items.add(item);
    }

    @ManagedOperation
    public String getItem(int pos) {
        return items.get(pos);
    }

    @ManagedOperation
    public List<String> getItems() {
        return items;
    }


}
```

Currently I do not have any `XML` configuration.

I have the bean initialized in my configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected final SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public Resource jmxResource() {
        return new Resource();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you enable **remote** access to JMX?

Comment: no, I did not enable remote. I am looking out for configuration on how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable **remote** JMX access, you need to start your Spring Boot application with the following JVM parameter:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<port>
```

To configure file-based password authentication, add the following parameter:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=<file>
```

There are two predefined users: `monitorRole` and `controlRole`. By default, the former has only read access, the latter may also write (see `$JRE_HOME/lib/management/jmxremote.access`). Use `jmxremote.password.template` in `$JRE_HOME/lib/management` as a template for the password file and stick to those usernames. For example:

```
monitorRole <password>
controlRole <password>
```

Log in using either of those usernames and the password you specified.

Be advised that when using this method, passwords are stored in plain text and it is **not** recommended for production use. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html) on how to set up authentication using SSL client certificates or LDAP.

Comment: what would be username?  All I see in my template is `# monitorRole  QED
# controlRole   R&D`.

Comment: Don't let yourself be fooled by the "role" part, those are in fact the usernames. See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks. can I replace "monitorRole" with a different userName

Comment: Yes, you can. But then you would also have to grant access rights to that username via the `jmxremote.access` file. Don't make things complicated and just stick with the predefined usernames.